# Problems with follow request, ScalaWS

Tags: scala, http, curl, playframework

Currently i'm trying to convert this code: https://github.com/Massa191/Consultas_CNPJ_CPF_Receita_Federal to Scala,

Resumidely that code get a captcha, and after the fill returns the html in the protected page,  happen three redirects if the captcha is filled right,  PHP Curl generates that log:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0)
POST 
http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp 
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.receita.fazenda.gov.br
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASAQAQRS=IGANMIGBLEJPKLJDAECAHMPE;flag=1
Content-Length: 111
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

upload completely sent off: 111 out of 111 bytes
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
Via: 1.1 XXX.XX.XXX.XX (McAfee Web Gateway 7.5.2.6.0.21020)
Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 20:01:32 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Location: Cnpjreva_Solicitacao2.asp?cnpj=56961139000156
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Cache-control: private
Content-Length: 166
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: close
```

I'm using playframework and that code:

```
 def getPage(captcha: String) = Action.async{ implicit  request =>
  val url = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp"
  val newCookies = request.cookies.map( c => new Cookie(c.name, c.value, maxAge = Some(0) , httpOnly = false,  path = "/" , domain = Some("www.receita.fazenda.gov.br")))

  val formData = Map(
    "origem" -> Seq("comprovante"),
    "cnpj" -> Seq("56961139000156"),
    "txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br" -> Seq(captcha),
    "submit1" -> Seq("Consultar"),
    "search_type" -> Seq("cnpj"))

  val headers = Seq(
    "Host" -> "www.receita.fazenda.gov.br",
    "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",
    "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language" -> "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Connection" -> "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1",
    "Proxy-Connection" -> "Keep-Alive",
    "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length" -> "111"
  )


  val cookieName = request.session.data.get("id")
  val newCookie = cookieName.map( s => Source.fromFile(s"cookies/$s").getLines().mkString(""))

  val req = ws.url(url).withHeaders("Cookie" -> newCookie.getOrElse(""))
                       .withFollowRedirects(true)
                       .withRequestFilter(AhcCurlRequestLogger())
                       .withBody(formData)
                       .withMethod("POST")
                       .withHeaders(headers:_*)
  req.execute().map{ resp =>
      println(resp.body)
      println(resp)
      Ok("DONE")
  }
}
```

The play output is this:

```
 p.a.l.w.a.AhcCurlRequestLogger - curl \
 --verbose \
 --request POST \
 --header 'Host: www.receita.fazenda.gov.br' \
 --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
 --header 'Cookie: flag=1; ASPSESSIONIDCQAQBRST=ODFCFIEDEFGIHNAJCOEONJMB' \
 --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
 --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --header 'Content-Length: 111' \
 --header 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' \
 --header 'Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive' \
 --header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
 --data 'txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br=v7xcnp&search_type=cnpj&cnpj=56961139000156&origem=comprovante&submit1=Consultar' \
  'http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp'
```

Every time I send the request from play, i receive status 200 from the page, but with PHP curl the redirect always works, can anyone help me?

Comment: the behaviour of play might be the expected, please look this https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: So this means PHP CURL is behaving in a wrong way?
Can i set a "confirmation" with my request?